# how to make column bool data to be true with the update of another column in same table?

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core

I have a data table where I have "Complete" (data type=>bool)column, "Total" (data type=>string)column and some other data fields. I have made the default value of "Complete" to false. I want to make it to be changed to true when I am updating the value of Total.

Whenever the value of total>0, the boolean value of "Complete" must be changed to "true".

[image: This is the data table]

As for an example, in here i have updated the total value to 20. (that means not null) the "complete" is still false. I want it to be changed to true when I have updated the value of "total".

Here is the code segment where I am updating the value of "Total" in reactjs.

```
const Order = () => {
    const [order, setOrder] = useState({
        address: "",
        customerId: "",
        customerName: "",
        dateTime: "",
        email: "",
        imageFile: "",
        imageName: "",
        orderID: "",
        patientAge: "",
        patientName: "",
        pharmacyId: "",
        pharmacyName: "",
        status: "",
        status2: "",
        teleNo: "",
        imageSrc:"",
        total:""
    });
    const {orderID} = useParams();
    
    const { total } = order

    const onInputChange = e => {
        setOrder({ ...order, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
      };

    let history=useHistory();
      const onSubmit = async e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            await axios.put(`https://localhost:44357/api/Orders/${orderID}`,order);
            history.push("/");
        };
        

    return (
        <div className="container py-4">
           

      <div>
          <form onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
          <div className="form-group">
          <input type="string" className="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Total amount" name="total" value={total} onChange={e => onInputChange(e)}/>
        <button className="btn btn-warning btn-block">Send Total</button>
        </div> 
        </form>
      </div>
      
    
        </div>
    )
};

export default Order;
```

Here is the Model:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace E_Pharmacy.Models
{
    public class Order
    {
        [Key]
        public int OrderID { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

        public string Status { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue(false)]
        public bool Complete { get; set; }
        public string Status2 { get; set; }
        public string PharmacyName { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public string PatientName { get; set; }
        public int PatientAge { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int TeleNo { get; set; }
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }

        public string Total { get; set; }

        
        public string ImageName{ get; set;}

        [NotMapped]
        public IFormFile ImageFile { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public String ImageSrc { get; set; }
        //[ForeignKey("Pharmacy")]
        public int PharmacyId { get; set; }
        //public Pharmacy Pharmacy { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

Here is the constructor:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using E_Pharmacy.Data;
using E_Pharmacy.Models;
using E_Pharmacy.Service;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using System.IO;

namespace E_Pharmacy.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class OrdersController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly PharmacyDataContext _context;
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostEnvironment;
        


        public OrdersController(PharmacyDataContext context, IWebHostEnvironment hostEnvironment)
          
        {
            _context = context;
            this._hostEnvironment = hostEnvironment;

        }

        

        /*// GET: api/Orders
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Order>>> GetOrder()
        {
         return await _context.Order.ToListAsync();
         }*/

        //GET: api/Orders/
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Order>>> GetOrder(string field, int value1, string value2, DateTime date)
        
            
                return await _context.Order.ToListAsync();
        }


            /*

            return NotFound();
        }*/

        // GET: api/Orders
        [HttpGet("{field}/{value}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Order>>> GetOrder(string field, int value)
        {
            if (field == "PharmacyId")
            {
                return await _context.Order.Where(p => p.PharmacyId == value).ToListAsync();
            }

            

            else if (field == "all")
            {
                return await _context.Order.ToListAsync();
            }

            return NotFound();
        }

        // GET: api/Orders/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Order>> GetOrder(int id)
        {
            var order = await _context.Order.FindAsync(id);

            if (order == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return order;
        }

        // PUT: api/Orders/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754.
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutOrder(int id, Order order)
        {
            if (id != order.OrderID)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!OrderExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }

        // POST: api/Orders
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754.
        [HttpPost]
        //[Route("api/Orders")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Order>> PostOrder([FromForm] Order order)
        {
            order.ImageName = await SaveImage(order.ImageFile); //save image

            _context.Order.Add(order);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return StatusCode(201);
        }

        // DELETE: api/Orders/5

        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Order>> DeleteOrder(int id)
        {
            var order = await _context.Order.FindAsync(id);
            if (order == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Order.Remove(order);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return order;
        }



        private bool OrderExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Order.Any(e => e.OrderID == id);
        }

        [NonAction]

        
    }
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what “Total” values constitute what the “Complete” value should be. What if the value is over 20? What “Total” values make “Complete” `true` and what “Total” values make “Complete” `false`? If the data is in a `DataTable` you may want to set the “Complete” column as an “Expression” column…   [DataColumn.Expression Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=net-5.0)

Comment: @JohnG. Whenever the value of total>0, the  boolean value of "Complete" must be changed to "true". I am an absolute beginner in this and I have no prior experience in this kind. hence I don't know whether it is possible or not to do this.

Comment: If you have access to the `DataTable` that holds the data... then make the "Complete" column an "Expression" column. Something like... `yourDataTableName.Columns["Complete"].Expression = "IIF(Total > 0, true, false)";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, `Complete` in `Order` should return true if `Total` is not null.

So then you can change Order to be like this.

```
public class Order
{
    //Start is unchanged, omitted for brevity
    ...

    //Changes here

    public bool Complete { get { return !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Total); } }

    //Rest is unchanged, omitted for brevity
    ...
}
```

So what this does, it only has a getter (so you can't set anything) and it checks and  returns `true` if `Total` is not null, or whitespace, otherwise false.

I don't understand why you have a Total value that is set as a String however, this seems strange.  I would suggest maybe change this to a decimal (if it should be a monetary value, otherwise int or float maybe) and you can use a nullable decimal if required.  Then your code would be like this

```
public class Order
{
    //Start is unchanged, omitted for brevity
    ...

    //New Total
    public decimal? Total { get; set; } = null;  


    public bool Complete { get { return !(this.Total == null || this.Total == 0m); } }

    //Rest is unchanged, omitted for brevity
    ...
}
```

This will then return true if total is null or zero.  You can remove the zero check if you don't need that.

Comment: I tried changing the data type of "total" property to decimal. But it didn't worked somehow. But keeping it as string worked.